# Text Recognition using ocr of Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr, matlab-cvst

I am trying to do OCR of this image-

[image]

This is what I am doing using `ocr` of `MATLAB`-

```
I=imread('N.jpg');
r = ocr(I,'TextLayout','Word')
```

But instead of getting `N` as `Text` this is what I am getting-

```
r = 

  ocrText with properties:

                      Text: 'I\/

'
    CharacterBoundingBoxes: [5x4 double]
      CharacterConfidences: [5x1 single]
                     Words: {'I\/'}
         WordBoundingBoxes: [276 120 13 7]
           WordConfidences: 0.7718
```

So,basically I am getting `I\/` as text.How can I fix this?

Comment: Is that supposed to be an N? I kinda understand that ocr gives you that result XD

Comment: Yes this is supposed to be `N`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dilate the image with a vertical line structuring element in order to vertically elongate the symbol and make it somewhat look more like a N.

Eg:

```
clear
clc

I=imread('N.jpg');

%// Line oriented at 90 degrees.
SE = strel('line',4,90);
I = imdilate(I,SE);

imshow(I)

r = ocr(I,'TextLayout','Word')
```

Image:

[image]

ahh now it looks like a N...

And output:

```
r = 

  ocrText with properties:

                      Text: 'N

'
    CharacterBoundingBoxes: [3x4 double]
      CharacterConfidences: [3x1 single]
                     Words: {'N'}
         WordBoundingBoxes: [276 118 13 11]
           WordConfidences: 0.8150
```

Yay!

Comment: Thanks this works for this particular image.Although I have many similar images for which it may not work,but I got the idea how to deal with such images.Thanks again.

Comment: yeah that's what I was afraid would happen. Maybe you can find a few structuring elements that generally work for particular sets of letters...that's an interesting problem

Comment: elongate vertically is the proper term :P

Comment: @Benoit_11 - No idea.  I hate random downvotes.  It's happened to a few of my answers.... even when the question was well formulated.  One thing I was thinking was that whoever downvotes has to put in an obligatory reason why the downvote was justified.... though this is probably too invasive and certainly a breach of privacy... but those random downvotes really piss me off.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you @rayryeng that pisses me off as well. That's the 2nd time in 2 days that an answer of mine gets a downvote and I really can't see why. I mean I know this one for example is not the most elegant or developed answer but it answers the question just fine and the OP is happy about it...